# Computer Balloting - Is 2 rounds of 30/20 better chance than 1 round of 60/40?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, numerical-methods, random-variables

I have a chance of being randomly selected by a computer as a candidate. Is **two rounds of 30 applicants fighting for 20 candidate seats** BETTER than **one round of 60 applicants fighting for 40 seats**? For the former, if I didnt get chosen in the first round, I get to participate in the second round again (similarly 30 applicants fighting for 20 seats).

Does it make a difference? Do I have a higher chance of NOT BEING CHOSEN in 2 rounds of 30 applicants fighting for 20 seats or 60 applicants fighting for 40 seats? Or are they the same probability? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The method is symmetric in the participants and the expected number of seats any participant gets is therefore the same, $\frac23$ (because the expected number of seats awarded to all combined is $40=\frac23\cdot 60$. This is also the probability of getting a seat.

Answer (score 0):

You have a better chance with the former option.

With the latter, you have a $\frac{40}{60}=\frac{2}{3}$ chance of being selected by the computer.

The former option affords you a slightly higher chance of being selected. The probability you don't get chosen is $(\frac{1}{3})^{2}=\frac{1}{9}$. Thus, the probability of being selected is the complement of not being selected is $1-\frac{1}{9}=\frac{8}{9}.$

This option only allows for $50$ candidates, though, while the other option allows for $60$ candidates. $20$ candidates from round 1 are chosen, and the 10 that weren't get moved to round 2, where there will be 20 new candidates. $2\cdot 20+10=50$.

Comment: Yes, another who doesnt get selected from first round will be filtered to the second round.